# Await doesn't work and execution keeps going

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm trying to send an object as a result, but the return line executes before the query is complete even though I'm using await.
Using the debugger I saw that the res.status(200) executes before the query inside the service returns the result.

I tried putting it in a function and using then() but this also didn't work. I think I've used it wrong.

This is the controller.js I'm using await in.

```
let table = req.query.table;
    let namespace = req.query.namespace;
    table = table.toUpperCase();
    namespace = namespace.toLowerCase();

    try{
        let serviceResponse = await testService.GetAny(table, namespace);
        res.type('application/json').status(200).send(serviceResponse);
    }
```

This is the service where the query is executed.

```
client.exec(getScript, (err, res) => {
        if(err){
            return console.error('Connect error ', err);
        }

        console.log('inside exec');

        return res;
    });
```

Comment: What is `testService.GetAny`?

Comment: It's the name of the function the query executes in

Comment: does it return a Promise?

Comment: No, the service returns an object

Comment: does it perform anything asynchronously? If so, how do you know when it's done? note: no use in `await`ing something that isn't a promise